# FB Customer Chat Plugin doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat, messenger

I have problem with adding a chat to the website. The code below works on one page, but **doesn't work on another**. The domain is added to the whitelist. Does anyone have any idea why this could happen?

```js
 Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v4.0'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!-- Your customer chat code -->
    <div class="fb-customerchat" 
    attribution=setup_tool 
    page_id="********" 
    theme_color="#000000" 
    logged_in_greeting="Lorem Ipsum" 
    logged_out_greeting="Lorem Ipsum"></div>
```

Comment: You should tag the question with the appropriate languages so people are more likely to see this